# Where can I see my Bitcoin address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, address

I use the original client, but I don't know where can I find my Bitcoin address. Can someone help me?

Comment: You don't have "an address", you have many addresses.  Though Bitcoin doesn't force you to do this, Bitcoin was built in a way so that you have a new address for each transaction where you receive bitcoins.

Comment: I think this question needs to be rephrased to include the version number, or it may become confusing as changes are made to the client. @Rowt, can you do that please, since you know which version you have?

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the standard client
2. Go to "Receive coins" tab
3. You will have a list of addresses you can use

If you want to create a new address, just click "New Address..." on the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are running the MultiBit wallet, you can find your Bitcoin Address here:
1) Go to the Request tab,
2) [image: Your address]

Comment: The is explicitly asking for the Satoshi Client, not Multibit.