# Where can i see my BitCoin addresses?

Tags: bitcoin-core, change

How can i see all my BitCoin addresses?

## Background

If i send a payment to someone (e.g. `0.35 BTC`), the BitCoin protocol is unable to send just `0.35 BTC` to someone. For example, if i own `1 BTC`, and want to spend `0.35 BTC`, then a transaction is created so send my entire `1 BTC` to two different people:

- 0.35 BTC to [destination addresses]
- remaining 0.65 BTC to [an new randomly generated address that i own]

This was horribly confusing thing to me, and nearly everyone else. Most people assume that if they backup their public and private key, that they have backed up their wallet.

Unfortunately, you do not have just the one address that appears in BitCoin-qt, you own ***n*** secret addresses, that are not visible in your wallet.

## A Concrete Example

Lets take [a real transaction from the blockchain](https://blockchain.info/tx/27f8fbbcaa5ce61e90f220f35c245f62c4366eeb8a292e02449f8703b6803fb1):

- Source Address
   `18888888PPJ8oGeqR6AKmoiKUme9da48Xf`: 2.3899 BTC
- Destination Addresses
   `1FvLq2vz7neRJeLk1uXGjg1Jk8FCiaHnwk`: 2 BTC
   `18888888PPJ8oGeqR6AKmoiKUme9da48Xf`: 0.3898 BTC

Out there is a guy who owns address [18888888PPJ8oGeqR6AKmoiKUme9da48Xf](https://blockchain.info/address/18888888PPJ8oGeqR6AKmoiKUme9da48Xf) (which had a balance of `2.3899 BTC`). He then spent `2 BTC` on something. The *"change"* is then routed back to a new address inside his client ([18888888PPJ8oGeqR6AKmoiKUme9da48Xf](https://blockchain.info/address/18888888PPJ8oGeqR6AKmoiKUme9da48Xf))

## You never see this address

The problem is that now you own another address; another randomly generated public/private key pair. If you lost your wallet right now, and restored from a backup, you would not have access to that change, because you don't have the key pair for this new, secret, hidden, address.

You only backup the key pair for your single "real" address. With every transaction BitCoinQt creates internal, secret, invisible addresses. They are hidden inside your wallet.

i want to backup ***all*** my public-private key pairs to paper. But before i reach that point, i want to be ***see*** all my public-private key pairs. i need to see all my addresses.

How can i see all my BitCoin addresses?

**BitCoinQt**: v0.8.1-beta

Alternatively, in order to ensure the security of my BitCoins, after every transaction should i generate a transaction

- **From**: me
- **To**: me

so that all my coins end up in a *"real"* address, which i can then backup? Is that something that is a best practice.

Losing BitCoins because my money was sitting in secret addresses was...depressing.

## Bonus Chatter

From the BitCoin wiki entry for [Change](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Change):

> The wallet file contains the private keys for change addresses, and they can receive and send coins normally. However, the GUI in the default client does not display them in the address book.

Also note: i'm not talking about backing up to a `wallet.dat` file. That will backup my wallet, but to a file. i have a backup of my single address; which is insufficient because my single address no longer has any bitcoins.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld My simple Bing search led me to http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3706/where-can-i-see-my-bitcoin-address

Comment: I would say since we're talking specifically about change addresses not showing in the GUI that 9077 would be more applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pywallet](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=34028.0) to look at all the addresses and keys.

The console command listaddressgroupings should also give you all your addresses, grouped by known co-ownership. You can then use dumpprivkey to get the corresponding key.

However, backing up just specific keys is not a recommend practice, you should back up the wallet file. If you do want a more concise method, you should use a client that supports deterministic wallets.

Comment: Are there any clients that support deterministic wallets?

Comment: @IanBoyd: Armory and Electrum. Bitcoin-qt 0.9 will also support this AFAIK.